# Using existing "dependency list" files in Makefile

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I have a web application that I'm trying to convert to use a Makefile for building.

I have an "input" directory that contains source files as well as "list" files that define concatenations of the source files:

```
js/common.js
js/other_utils.js
js/component1.js
js/component2.js
js/app_logic.js
js/admin_logic.js
js/app.js.list     # common.js other_utils.js component1.js component2.js app_logic.js
js/admin.js.list   # common.js admin_logic.js
```

I want to "output" files to be determined by these list files like so:

```
static/app.js
static/admin.js
```

…with targets rebuilt only as necessary (e.g. `static/admin.js` would be rebuilt iff `js/admin.js.list` or `js/common.js` or `js/admin_logic.js` were modified.)

Is there a way to do this without generating "extra" included makefiles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way using GNU Make's secondary expansion feature! This lets me create a prerequisites list based on the *contents* of the "main" list file prerequisite:

```
.PHONY: js
jsfiles = $(shell ls -1 js/*.js.list)
js: $(jsfiles:js/%.js.list=static/%.js)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
static/%.js: js/%.js.list $$(shell cat js/%.js.list | sed 's/^/js\//')
    echo "compile" $^
```